# Inline JS not working in FF, with no error message

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML with inline JS for a select field which I also want to act as an input.

```
<select name="tax_rate" id="tax_rate" class="form-control text-center"
        dir="rtl" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=='customOption')
        {toggleField(this,this.nextElementSibling); this.selectedIndex='0';}"
        style="display: inline;">
    <option value="0">0.00</option>
    <option value="customOption">[New Rate]</option>
    <option value="0.1500" selected="">15.00</option>
</select>
```

This code works perfectly in Safari, Chrome, IE, Edge, but not in latest FF, and with no error in console. It just does not hide the select and shows the input (and vice versa).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not good practice to use code there! Just wrap your code in a function and attach it to the click event using `addEventListener`!

Comment: Hi @ibrahim mahrir I fixed it by extracting the code, but what I still do not understand is why perfectly valid JS works in 3 out of 4 major browsers and not on the last. Thanks.

Comment: There is still some mysterious parts of your code. For example `toggleField`. Where is and what does it do?